How to create a control that is able to be expanded bigger than Parent control in WinUI 3
I would like to create a control that can be expanded and is able to be shown even though the size is bigger than its parent control. I need a TextBox to input something and  expand the control when text entered  to show some buttons. Just like when the AutoSuggestBox or web browser's address bar received suggestions, the area is expanded and float on the surface.
this is an AutoSuggestBox
I have tried to put anything I want to show in a Flyout and then make the Flyout floats over the original controls.
<Flyout x:Name="myFlyout">
    <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
        <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-15,0,0"/>
            <!-- -15 margin makes it float over the attached control-->
        </Style>
    </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentArea" Width="800">
        <StackPanel x:Name="FlyoutStack">
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Flyout>

public void ShowFlyout()
{
    /**
    BaseGrid is the grid contains textbox
    TextBoxPart is a TextBox
    And the Flyout is attached to BaseGrid.
    */
    BaseGrid.Children.Remove(TextBoxPart);
    // move the textbox from BaseGrid to Flyout
    try { FlyoutStack.Children.Insert(0, SearchBoxPart); }
    catch (Exception e){ }
    SearchBoxFlyout.ShowAt(BaseGrid); //show the flyout
}

But when the text is in complex language. Moving the textbox will cause the received character disappeared. Is there any alternative way to expend the control?
Update
Here is my new code, SearchBox is my class.
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxText = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(myText),
    typeof(string), 
    typeof(SearchBox),
    new PropertyMetadata(default, (sender, args) =>
    {
        ((SearchBox)sender).TextChanged();
    }));

public string myText
{
    get => (string)GetValue(TextBoxText);
    set => SetValue(TextBoxText, value);
}

public void TextChanged()
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"{TextBoxControl.Text}////{TextBoxOnFlyout.Text}////{myText}");
// When I enter text in TextBoxControl myText Changed but TexBoxOnFlyout doesn't
}

<Grid x:Name="BaseGrid">
    <TextBox
        x:Name="TextBoxControl"
        Text="{x:Bind myText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <Flyout x:Name="SearchBoxFlyout">
            <Grid x:Name="ContentArea">
                <StackPanel x:Name="FlyoutStack">
                    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxOnFlyout" Text="{x:Bind myText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Flyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</Grid>


See: FlyoutBase.Placement property.

I have already set the placement of my flyout. But there are some problems when moving textbox to flyout. Or do you mean I can just set the textbox on the flyout and always showing it instead of moving it between flyout and grid?

A flyout is a "content control".  My "flyout adapter" (overloads) accept a string or a UIElement; add it to a Flyout; and then displays the flyout. In the case of a string, it's first wrapped in a TextBlock. For "fancy", like a "splash", I'll have a (display-only) user control and put "that" into the flyout before displaying it. Yes; build it first; then display it where you want.

I tried to do it but the thing is in Complex language, 2-3 characters form a word. Not like alphabets in English. So when I only click on 1 character, it is not completed and putting it to another textbox will make it "a character"(not a word).

The "complex characters" you refer to are simply "unicodes" for "a given font" strung together as characters ... making a "string"; e.g.  public static string TrigramForHeaven { get { return char.ConvertFromUtf32( 0x2630 ); } }

Actually we are using some symbols that stand for pronunciation. So, each symbol is a Unicode but combining them makes a whole new different character. e.g. "ㄏ"(sounds like "H" in "hi") + "ㄞ"(sounds like "I") plus a symbol for accent becomes "嗨"(Hi,  the meaning and pronunciation of this word is derived from English)

Instead of moving TextBoxes, you can just create a DependencyProperty and bind it to each TextBox.
For example:
FlyoutTextBox.xaml
<UserControl
    x:Class="WinUIApp.FlyoutTextBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUIApp10"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox
            x:Name="TextBoxControl"
            Text="{x:Bind Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <Grid.ContextFlyout>
            <Flyout
                x:Name="Flyout"
                Placement="Bottom">
                <TextBox
                    Loaded="FlytoutTextBox_Loaded"
                    Text="{x:Bind Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </Flyout>
        </Grid.ContextFlyout>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>

FlyoutTextBox.xaml.cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace WinUIApp;

public sealed partial class FlyoutTextBox : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Text),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(FlyoutTextBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(default, (d, e) => (d as FlyoutTextBox)?.OnTextChanged()));

    public FlyoutTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    private void OnTextChanged()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text) is false)
        {
            Flyout.ShowAt(TextBoxControl);
        }
    }

    private void FlytoutTextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is not TextBox textBox)
        {
            return;
        }

        textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
    }
}


I think there are some problems with my Binding, I copied your xaml and c# code and changed some names. But when I enter some text in one textbox, text in the other textbox doesn't change

I actually confirmed that the code in my answer works. Can you share your code based on my answer?

I have already paste my code under #update. I changed some names. But I don't know if I changed something critical that caused the problem

I guess the binding is failing because you didn't follow the naming rules for DependencyProperty. Go with "myText" / "myTextProperty" or "TextBoxText" / "TextBoxTextProperty".

Yes now it works but when I entered complex language the character (In my case: Chinese) still disappeared. Is it possible to fix the problem of complex language (IME). Or maybe I have to use something like `BeforeTextChange'?

That's weird. I don't have that issue in Japanese. What do you mean by "disappeared"? No text in the flyout? Also, can you reproduce that issue if you place both TextBoxes on the same StackPanel? (No flyout)

I am Taiwanese so we type with something called Bopomofo. Type any symbol like "ㄅ" and the PropertyChanged will be triggered. And then the textbox on the flyout appeared but nothing in the text. English works correctly

I guess that issue is not related to the original question. Can you post a new question for the new issue?

If this answer was helpful, please accept it as the answer so we can close this session.

I updated my answer with a Loaded event to fix the cursor issue when the flyout is open.

Thank you. I deleted the comment because I found that I can use Select() to set the cursor.
